# copy 4 byte number to character array

Tags: c

I want to store a 4 byte number to a character array.

```
uint32 u32_gen;

u32_gen = func(X,Y,Z);

u32_gen is 4 bytes. For example it's value is 65DA929D. I want to store this as:

char buf[100] = {'\0'};
buffer[7]=65;
buffer[8]=DA;
buffer[9]=92;
buffer[10]9D;
```

What I am doing and stuck:

```
int num = 0;

num = ((u32_gen & 0xFF000000) >> 24) ;  num value is 101
num = ((u32_gen & 0x00FF0000) >> 16) ;  num value is 218
num = ((u32_gen & 0x0000FF00) >> 8) ;   num value is 146
num = (u32_gen & 0x000000FF) ;          num value is 157
```

I need to copy this num which is decimal value to buffer[7]..buffer[10] between each calculation. I have read several related posts in Stackoverflow and other books. Do I have to write a program to convert this num from decimal to hex?

Comment: The value stored in each of `buffer[7]` .. `buffer[10]` can be regarded as hex or as decimal (the value is arguably just binary). There is no conversion needed until you present it as a string.

Comment: If you're asking about "converting from decimal to hex", you should brush up your computer science and maths basics before turning to C...

Comment: @KerrekSB +1 on the comment, and if you're following the comments on this post (both Q&A) and *not* laughing silently you have ice-water in your veins.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
buffer[7] = (char)num;
...
```

Another option would be to declare a union like this:

```
union data
{
    char s[4];
    uint32 u32_gen;
} myData;
```

Then do somthing like:

```
myData.u32_gen = func(X,Y,Z);
buffer[7] = myData.s[0];
buffer[8] = myData.s[1];
buffer[9] = myData.s[2];
buffer[10] = myData.s[3];
```

Comment: No this is not working. Casting to fewer bits number will just lose all the higher part.

Comment: But you don't need the higher part, you have already bit shifted the value.

Comment: I am talking about your first line. This will only assign the lowest ( or highest on little endian) to num[7], no 8,9,10

Comment: The first line in this answer will *never* store any of the higher bytes of a multi-byte unsigned into buffer[7] on *any* platform *regardless of endianness*.

Comment: lol, I assumed it would be obvious that you needed to add another three lines, for 8, 9 and 10. My mistake.